# The .on() method won't fire in some situations

Tags: jquery

There are some situations that the .on() event method doesn't fire but the .live() does fire. 
However, As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.
 So it's better to use .on() method to attach event handlers.

So here is the problem - http://jsfiddle.net/rGRdT/2/ 
You can see that the .one() method is called once when you click the button, but when you click the second button that is just created, the .on() will not be called.

```
$('#button2').on('click', function() {
    $('div').append('<input type="button" value="add2" id="button3" />'); 
});
```

You can see here - http://jsfiddle.net/GFCt9/ 
That the .live() method is called perfectly when you click the second button.

```
$('#button2').live('click', function() {
    $('div').append('<input type="button" value="add2" id="button3" />');
});​
```

So how can I use the .on() method so it will work like .live() method in the example above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#button2').live('click', function() {
```

isn't equivalent to

```
$('#button2').on('click', function() {
```

but to

```
$(document).on('click', '#button2', function() { // you may replace document with something more precise but existing
```

If your element with id `button2` doesn't exist when you call `$('#button2').on`, you're not binding anything. This is very different from `live`. You must call `on` on a non empty collection.

[`Sample`](http://jsfiddle.net/rGRdT/6/)

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that!

Answer (score 0):

Your example "non-working" jsfiddle script has a bug that prevents it from working: a simple javascript error in `('di'v).on(` that prevented *all* the script from running.

Try [your fiddle, updated](http://jsfiddle.net/rGRdT/7/) to see the `.on()` syntax working as you would expect. In the simple case you provided, there is no need for using `.live()` and no need for the new method `.on('event', 'selector', fn)` either.